# Using C# 4.0 to run Python scripts error non-ascii char

Tags: c#, python

I eventually want to be able to return a DataFrame from Python to C#. At the moment I am running a very simple console app to try and run a basic Python script. This script compiles and runs in Canopy fine however when I run it from C# I get the error relating to non-ASCII chars.

I have read many articles relating to this but none of them seem to resolve the issue I have.

Error
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canop
y32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\python.exe on line 1, but no encoding
declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details

Thx in advance for any help!

```
static int test_python_canopy()
{
    string cmd;
    string args;

    args = "C:\\Share\\Python\\test.py";

    cmd = @"C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\python.exe";
    cmd = "\"" + cmd + "\"";

    ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
    start.FileName = cmd;
    start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
    start.UseShellExecute = false;
    start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
        {
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.Write(result);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The Python script i am running is

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

print "Hi!!"

import sys
path = sys.argv[0]  #1 argument given is a string for the path
sys.path.append(path)

def MethodCall(OutputString):
    print OutputString
    
MethodCall("Hello World!")

Comment: L2 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ProcessStartInfo`, `FileName` should be set to the executable that you wish to run and `Arguments` should be set to the arguments that you want to pass to that executable.

In your code, `FileName` is set correctly to the Python interpreter. `Arguments`, however, the first argument is being set to Python interpreter. The net result is that C# is trying to execute this command:

```
C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\python.exe C:\Program Files\Enthought\Canopy32\App\appdata\canopy-1.5.2.2785.win-x86\python.exe C:\Share\Python\test.py
```

which means that Python is trying to use the Python executable as a script, which is not going to work. Changing the line that sets the arguments should fix the problem:

```
start.Arguments = args;
```